# invalid keyword argument for print()

Tags: python, printing, arguments, keyword

When I wrote this code:

```
b = 5
a = b
c = a
print(a)
print(z=c*a)
print(z+b)
```

I got this error:

```
TypeError: 'z' is an invalid keyword argument for print()
```

So I decided to make a variable z and changed my code to this:

```
b = 5
a = b
c = a
print(a)
z
print(z=c*a)
print(z+b)
```

I still got the same error:

```
TypeError: 'z' is an invalid keyword argument for print()
```

It worked when I wrote:

```
b = 5
a = b
c = a
print(a)
z=c*a
print(z)
print(z+b)
```

Why was I getting an error on the first two attempts and what does 'invalid keyword argument for print()' mean?

Comment: See e.g. https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html#keyword-arguments - it means what it says, [`print`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#print) doesn't define a keyword argument named `z`. Also assignments are *statements* in Python, not expressions returning the assigned value like in e.g. JavaScript.

Comment: What did you expect `print(z=c*a)` to do? What effect were you trying to achieve with that line?

Comment: I wanted to see if I can create a variable directly in a print statement  and assign it a value without introducing it in the prior code.

Comment: using python 3.8 it is possible by `walrus operator` which is `:=`, then replace  `print(z:=c*a)`. it would assign z and print it. no need for extra line, check the answer that I posted

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The built-in print() function simply prints whatever the stuff in the brackets 'returns'.

`z = c * a` Doesn't 'return' anything, it just defines what z is.

When you write `z = c * a` and then `print(z)`, stating the variable z returns its value and so the print statement has a result to print.

Answer (score 3):

If you use python 3.8 it is possible by `:=` as known the walrus operator, check definitions [here](https://docs.python.org/3/whatsnew/3.8.html)
try this:

```
b = 5
a = b
c = a
print(a)
print(z:=c*a)
print(z+b)
```

Output:

```
5
25
30
```

Comment: This is a terrible abuse of assignment expressions. It mashes separate concerns into one line at the expense of readability. This kind of thing is why assignment expressions were excluded for so long, and why their inclusion in Python 3.8 was one of the most divisive changes in Python history.

Answer (score 0):

In python, print is a function, which means you can't declare or assign values to variables within it. In some functions, you can specify parameters such as `encoding=""` in the open function where encoding is the keyword. There is no 'z' keyword for the print statement. The last time, it worked because you assigned the variable before the print statement and then printed it.

Try to do some basic research before you ask here, as this is not too complicated

Answer (score 0):

You can't assign a value to z in the print function, that is related to the 2nd print line, if you print the addition by itself or print z after assigning the value to it in a separate line.